# Convergent Subsequence of a Sequence in a Gelfand Triple

Tags: reference-request, hilbert-spaces, equicontinuity

In my lecture notes of a class I took I found the following result. Unfortunately, I can't find a reference for the result. Does anyone have a reference or a hint where I could find the result?

Lemma: Let $(V,H,V^{\prime})$ be a Gelfand triple. Given $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ bounded in $L^2([0,T]; V) \cap L^{\infty}([0,T];H)$ and equicontinuous as $V^{\prime}$-valued functions and such that $u_n(0) \to u(0)$ strongly in $H$, one can extract a subsequence converging strongly in $L^2([0,T];H)$.

Any help is appreciated!

Best,
Luke

Comment: seems to be related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma

Comment: Hi, thanks for that hint. I found my statement as an exercise when I googled Aubin-Lions. I couldn't find a reference, though. I would still be happy if anyone could provide me with one.